# C++ Pass Point on default constructor

Tags: c++

Hy guys, if i have this twos class:

```
class game{

int num;
string name;
Equip e;

public:
game(string n = "Default",int i = 2,Equip &tmp = NULL):name(n),num(i),e(tmp){};
.
.
//Sets and Gets
.
};
```

and

```
class Equip{
    int x;
public:
    //contructor of Equip
    .
    .
    //Sets and Gets
    .
};
```

if on main code i have:

```
int main(){
Equip A();
Game g("Zuup",2,*A);

.
.
.

}
```

how i pass to the other class one point like this?
PS. this code is a example.

Someon can help me?

Best.

Comment: Example or not, it needs to make sense. I highly doubt you were trying to make a function and dereference a pointer to it. References can't be `NULL` (nor the concept null) either.

Comment: NULL exists only for the default constructor does not give error

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example is none of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have understood your question. As your code as you say is simply an example I will not discuss its defects.

So the main could look the following way

```
int main()
{
   Equip e;
   Game g( "Zuup",2, &e);
```

Or maybe

```
int main()
{
   Equip *e = new Equip();
   Game g( "Zuup",2, e);
```

It depends of how your classes are defined.

Or even you can define one more constructor

```
game( Equip *e  ) : game( "Defailt", 2, e ){};
```

Answer (score 1):

lots of errors (some of them bellow):

this:

```
game(string n = "Default",int i = 2,Equip &tmp = NULL)
```

should be :

```
game(string n = "Default",int i = 2,Equip *tmp = NULL)
```

also:

```
Equip A();
```

will give you probably "most vexing parse" problem

and:

```
Game g("Zuup",2,*A);
```

should be:

```
Game g("Zuup",2,&A);
```

but in the end you are passing a Equip object instance pointer to your Game, isnt that what you want?

Comment: Ty for help me. Lets go try this.

Comment: compiler output will help you:)